# Possible to mark associated objects to delete

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've a model associated to another. Is it possible to mark the associated model to delete if the original model will be saved? In the original model accepts_nested_attributes_for :ass_model is activated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. You just need to add `allow_destroy: true` option to `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and pass `_destroy: true` as nested attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **Yes**

Long Answer (Copied from here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :avatar
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :avatar, allow_destroy: true
end
```

> Now, when you add the _destroy key to the attributes hash, with a value that evaluates to true, you will destroy the associated model:

```
member.avatar_attributes = { id: '2', _destroy: '1' }
member.avatar.marked_for_destruction? # => true
member.save
member.reload.avatar # => nil
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not allowed to manipulate the params-hash from the controller? How should I do that?

Comment: @Gerrit how to do what? You're asking how to allow `_destroy` param through strong parameters?

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing this in code instead of applying some form attributes you can just call `mark_for_destruction` on the model.

```
member.avatar.mark_for_destruction
member.save # this deletes the avatar
```

[Documentation on APIDock](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation/mark_for_destruction)